# Уравнение окружности. Найти угол при известном радиусе, координатах и центре окружности

Tags: c#, математика

Нужно сделать движение по окружности с указанной точки.
С помощью параметрического уравнения уравнения окружности я нахожу координаты, для последующего движения объекта. 
Мне нужно найти значение angle при указанных координатах, например, сколько будет angle при x и z равных нулю. Как найти этот угол? 
center - это координаты центра окружности,

```
double x = radius * Math.Cos(angle) + centerX;
double z = radius * Math.Sin(angle) + centerZ;
```

Comment: Не любая окружность имеет точку (0, 0)

Comment: @vp_arth я же написал "например", какие там значения будут это не важно, важно угол найти при определенных значениях, формула же должна быть какая-то, просто я в геометрии не шарю, вот и спрашиваю

Comment: `tan(angle) = (z - centerZ) / (x - centerX)`, потом скорректируйте четверть в зависимости от знаков в числителе и знаменателе. Например `1 / 1 = 1` - это первая четверть, а `-1 / (-1) = 1` - это третья

Comment: @АндрейNOP что-то не получается, пытаюсь так найти угол,  double angle2 = Math.Atan((z - 0.1) / (x - 2.16)); сравниваю, но значения разные

Comment: @ВадимМороз А должны быть - одинаковые?

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну я по формуле окружности нахожу координаты, потом вставляя эт же данные пытаюсь получить угол, по вашей формуле, чтобы проверить правильность и значения получаются разные

Comment: @ВадимМороз "по формуле окружности нахожу координаты" - как? "пытаюсь получить угол" - как? "значения получаются разные" - какие?

Comment: @АндрейNOP прочитайте условие задачи, угол получаю по ваше формуле tan(angle) = (z - centerZ) / (x - centerX) 
А угол сравниваю тот, что изначально был с тем, что получил по вашей формуле

Comment: @ВадимМороз, дополните вопрос конкретными примерами, что и как считаете.